# How to make this top bottom slide effect

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-carousel

I'm trying to make this slide effect, just like in: [dropbox link slider](https://www.dropbox.com/business). Just scroll down, till you see a monitor which has a `slider` within, and `captions` in the right. I tried a lot, but it is not the same effect. I don't understand how this transform is done on `ul` element. 
Any help very appreciated!

Here is what I tried so far:

```css
.carousel-inner>.item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  /*width: 33.33333%;*/
  bottom: 15px;
  opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: bottom 600ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), opacity 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), visibility 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  transition: bottom 600ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), opacity 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), height 600ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  -webkit-transition: bottom 600ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 200ms, opacity 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 200ms;
  transition: bottom 600ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 200ms, opacity 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 200ms;
  transform: none !important;
}
.carousel-inner>.item.active{
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  height: inherit;
  -webkit-transition: bottom 600ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), opacity 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  transition: bottom 600ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), opacity 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  -webkit-transition: bottom 600ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 150ms, opacity 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 150ms;
  transition: bottom 600ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 150ms, opacity 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 150ms;
  transform: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6 offset3">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide vertical">
                <!-- Carousel items -->
                <ul class="carousel-inner">
                    <li class="active item">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400&amp;text=First+Slide">
                    </li>
                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400&amp;text=Second+Slide">
                    </li>
                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400&amp;text=Third+Slide">
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- Carousel nav -->
                <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
                <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The dropbox link is broken for me.

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa, to me it works, I don't know why! :(

Answer (score 0):

The animation is on the `<li>`, not on the `<ul>`

Using bootstrap's carousel you should create a new class that handle the animation then trigger the event "slide.bs.carousel" to remove this class from current slide (which will "reverse" the transition) then trigger the event "slid.bs.carousel" to add the animation class to the new current slide.

see http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-events

Comment: Not animation, but transform! Look on the link I provided, inspect and you will see that they used a transform in the ul element for slides.

Comment: I don't get your question then, the transformX allows the ul to show a slide that's all. There is no effect on this.

Comment: But, how did they do that? Without that transform, I cannot achieve that effect! :(

Comment: Actually you can, there isn't any effect on the transformX.
The transformX on the <ul> is just there to show the current slide. 
There are 3 slides, each with a 33.33% width (33.33*3 = 99.99).
The transformX just move the <ul> from left to right with a 33.33% step

Comment: Yeh, I know that, but how did they do this with JQuery? Thnx for trying to help me!

Comment: Oh, they just do something like :

`var position = 0;
$('.arrow').on('click',function() {
  if(position === 99.99%) {
     position = 0;
  } else {
      position += 33.33%;
  }

  $('.my-carousel').css({transform: "translateX('+ position +')"});
}`

This snippet isn't perfect, but it's the idea

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood it right, you basically need a frame for your animation (like is the monitor on dropbox). You could just wrap your `carousel` in another div and give it a border (or use a background image, if you need that monitor).

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/631bjrwL/42/

Comment: I don't have any problem with appearance, read again my question! I asked for slide effects, and not for frame!